# Why are my vim colors different within a tmux session in the macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, colors, tmux

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my colors within vim in tmux. For some reason the colors seem correct everywhere except in vim. Every similar question I've found seemed to be resolved by setting TERM correctly in tmux and vim but that isn't working for me. In this case TERM is xterm-256color in both terminal sessions. I have tried it with TERM=screen-256color, and tried launching tmux with the "-2" option to force 256 color mode but get the same results.

The left image is vim inside tmux, right image is not.
[Color difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlycL.png)

Comment: I was having the same problem with gnome-terminal on Fedora.  Please see this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349035/124274) for the workaround I used to get consistent Vim colors both inside and outside of tmux.  It may or may not be applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `tmux-256color-italic.terminfo` and do `tic xterm-256color-italic.terminfo` in the terminal. Then in the `bashrc` paste `export TERM=xterm-256color-italic`

```
tmux-256color-italic|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
    sitm=\ePtmux;\e\E[3m\e\\, ritm=\ePtmux;\e\E[23m\e\\,
use=screen-256color,
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.